# Creating dynamic html table without using 'table'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I need to create an html tables without using the table tags or css display:table(and same) properties.

I wrote this html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Creating div tables</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flex.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="tbl"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $('.tbl').append('<div class="rw"></div>');
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            $('.rw').append('<div class="col col'+i.toString()+'">'+Math.random().toString()+'</div>');
        };  
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And this css:

```
.tbl {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;   
    flex-flow:column;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
}

.rw {
    background-color: rgb(197, 253, 255);
    display: flex;   
    flex-flow:row;
    resize:both;
}

.col {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Now, i need to do such, that if in a cell there is an overflow, the table perform a resizing of whole raw and/or column according to next scheme.

[image: Scheme of cells resizing]

At this moment only the raw resizing works.
How to implement the whole column resizing? Can i perform it only using CSS? Or I have to use JavaScript/Jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid tables?

Comment: Maybe check out the CSS rules concomitant with  `display:flex` container styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you need, but you can use a set of flexbox containers with flexible children to make a grid that adjusts to the amount of content in each child cell:

[image]

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#container{width:400px;}
.Grid {
  display: flex;
}
.Grid-cell {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
    <div id='container'>
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Grid-cell">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Grid">
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">A small bit of text.</div>
          <div class="Grid-cell">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```